# Getting Apache HTTP Server to fill in the file extension

Tags: apache, http

I'd like to let people access files on my root domain directory without having to specify the file extension.

So, for example, there is currently a z9.html that a browser can access with www.mysite.com/z9.html.  I would like to let people put in www.mysite.com/z9 to get the file.

The pecking order would be to look for a file of the name submitted with a .php extension, and then, if none found, look for a file of that name with a .html extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my question was downvoted.  It seems like a perfectly reasonable question for the Apache group.  The answer is to use Apache's mod_rewrite:

To map any filename without an extension to that filename + .html place the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^.]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```